# I want to know how to "Hide" a part of my code after it has been used and is no longer needed

Tags: python

I have been making a 5 question "Quiz" on Python. It is pretty simple in code design since I do not have much experience. I want to hide the previous questions so that the code is easier on the eyes and user friendly. I work on IDLE by the way.

```
i="Incorrect, You lost points for this question."
i2="Incorrect, Try Again."
g="Good Job!"
x=100 #percentage
q1=input("What is 2+3? ")
while q1 != "5":
    x-=20
    print (i,"Your current score:",x,"%")
    q1=input("What is 2+3? ")
    while q1 != "5" and (x<100):
        print (i2)
        q1=input("What is 2+3? ")
else:
    print(g)
    print("Your current score:",x,"%")

Q2=input("What are the first 3 digits of Pi? ")...
```

This goes on 4 more times. I want all text that I displayed for q1 to disappear when the input value for Q2 appears.

Comment: A start would be to store your questions and answers in a collection, such as a dict.

Answer (score 1):

Import the module os

```
import os

os.system('cls')
```

os.system('cls') will clear the screen on windows otherwise replace 'cls' with 'clear'
Just put tthat line whenever you want to clear everything on your code